# How to monitor script execution time and generate notifications at milestone intervals without terminating the script?

Tags: bash, timeout

Is there a way I can monitor the execution time of a script and generate notifications if the script is still running at milestone intervals?

AFAICS, `wait` in bash always blocks.

I intend using this in conjunction with STDOUT, STDERR capture to quieten down cron emails but I want notifications out if the script overruns its expected window (WITHOUT terminating it).

Google just keeps pointing me towards `time` and `timeout` which (in the absence of additional logic) are not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about running your process in background and just monitoring it using something like the following loop? You can also set up a counter in this case, for example to terminate the process if it takes 3 times longer than it should

```bash
# Interval for checking status
readonly interval=10

# Your task here, maybe with some output redirections
sleep 100 &

# Infinite loop
while true
do
    # Chill some time
    sleep "$interval"

    # Check if the background process still exists
    if ps -p "$!" &> /dev/null
    then
        # Do something here, again maybe with >> logfile
        echo "Process is still running!"
    fi
done
```

Comment: That would work very well - and I'm now banging my head off the desk for not thinking of it myself :)

Comment: Sometimes this happens to everyone. You're welcome! Moreover, now I can leave comments, so thank you lmao

Answer (score 0):

You may put this lines ahead of your script, and tune it. If execution of your task has different status, like `in_queue` and `started`, you write a corresponding signal to `&$fdtick` file descriptor, the timer will repeat that signal at intervals, also printing a newline every minute. Your loop may also include other watchdog functions of course.

**NOTE**: `>( ... )` is called process substitution and is a `bash` syntax that create and give a name to a pipe between a running process and a new coprocess. `<( ... )` does the same when the creator holds the read-end of the pipe.

```
############################################################
#                        VISUAL TIMER                      #
# >$fdtick : tick input file descriptor                    #
# >stderr : visual output                                  #
############################################################
exec {fdtick}> >(
  ((tick = 2, begintime = SECONDS))
  while read -t $tick dot || { (( $? > 128)) && dot=${odot:-#}; }; do
    odot=$dot
    (( lastmin = durationmin, durationtick = (duration = SECONDS - begintime) / tick, durationmin = duration / 60 ))
    while (( durationtick > lasttick )) ; do echo -n "$dot " ; ((lasttick++)) ; done
    (( durationmin == lastmin )) || echo $durationmin
  done >&2
) &&
trap "$(trap -p EXIT)"$'\n'"exec {fdtick}>&-" EXIT


sleep 50 ## long starting step
echo '.'>&$fdtick ## say the script is going on
sleep 50 ## long working step
## terminated, cleanup by trap EXIT
```